# Laravel5.2 upload image error

Tags: image, laravel, upload

I want to upload image to server. the create view page is :

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'imagesupload','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','method' => 'post']) !!}
{!! Form::file('image') !!}
{!! Form::submit('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My controller code is:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function store(Request $request)
{

    dd($request['image']);
}
```

My route is:

```
Route::post('imagesupload','ImagesController@store');
```

The page when I uploaded a image:

```
UploadedFile {#208 ▼
-test: false
-originalName: "WIN_20160626_17_24_33_Pro.jpg"
-mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
-size: 0
-error: 1
path: ""
filename: ""
basename: ""
pathname: ""
extension: ""
realPath: "/var/www/html/public"
aTime: 1970-01-01 08:00:00
mTime: 1970-01-01 08:00:00
cTime: 1970-01-01 08:00:00
inode: false
size: false
perms: 00
owner: false
group: false
type: false
writable: false
readable: false
executable: false
file: false
dir: false
link: false
}
```

there is a error. the image have no size.
Hope someone can tell me why. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something .You have to use $request->file('fieldname') inorder to access files.
Try dd( $request->file('image'));

Comment: I have tried. It's the same.  Input::file('image') can work. May be Request is not suit to post file. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

in view

```
   {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'imagesupload','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true)) !!}
    {!! Form::file('image') !!}
    <p class="errors">
    {!!$errors->first('image')!!}</p>
    @if(Session::has('error'))
    <p class="errors">{!! Session::get('error') !!}</p>
    @endif
    <div id="success"> </div>

    {!! Form::submit('Submit', array('class'=>'send-btn')) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

in controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Input;
use Validator;
use Redirect;
use Session;

public function store() {

// getting all of the post data
$file = array('image' => Input::file('image'));
// return $file;
 // setting up rules
$rules = array('image' => 'required',); //mimes:jpeg,bmp,png and for max size max:10000
// doing the validation, passing post data, rules and the messages

$validator = Validator::make($file, $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {
// send back to the page with the input data and errors
 return Redirect::to('uploadprofilepicture')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
 }
else {
                // checking file is valid.
                if (Input::file('image')->isValid()) {

                  $destinationPath = 'images/profile/'; // upload path
                  $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
                  $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; 
// renameing image
 // return $fileName; 
Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); 
// uploading file to given path
// sending back with message
Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully'); 
 }
 else {
 // sending back with error message.
  Session::flash('error', 'uploaded file is not valid');
  return Redirect::to('yourviewfile');
 }
}
}
```

Comment: use  Input::file('image'); instead of dd($request['image']);

Comment: Did you find my answer correct? can u mar it please?

Answer (score 0):

create a form with attribute ‘files’=>true inorder to upload files

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'imagesupload','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true)) !!}
```

In request you can get it via `$request->filename`